# How do I add new field to existing JSON?

Tags: python, pyspark

I converted a dataframe to json using toJSON()

```
df.toJSON().collect()
```

and this is the data I've got as an output

```
[
    {"alertId":"abcd20","score":1.23,"severity":0.123},
    {"alertId":"abcd20","score":1.23,"severity":0.123},
    {"alertId":"abc20","score":1.23,"severity":0.123}
]
```

I just want to add one field("alerts") to this json array like this

```
{
    "alerts": [
  {"alertId":"abcd20","score":1.23,"severity":0.123},
    {"alertId":"abcd20","score":1.23,"severity":0.123},
    {"alertId":"abc20","score":1.23,"severity":0.123}
       
    ]
}
```

the schema I want to use is

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("alerts", ArrayType(
        StructType([
            StructField("alertId", StringType(), True),
            StructField("score", DoubleType(), True),
            StructField("severity", DoubleType(), True),
        ])
    ))
])
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: You should add the field to the original dataframe before converting it to JSON.

Comment: Otherwise you have to parse all the JSON, add the field to each dictionary, then convert them back to JSON.

Comment: thank you for your comment! how do I do it to get the desired outcome? I have 3 columns in the dataframe ( "alertId","score","severity")

Comment: Sorry, I don't know PySpark, but it seems like adding columns to a dataframe should be a pretty basic operation.

Comment: This is not adding columns to a DataFrame.  He wants the entire contents of the DataFrame inside a new field.  Pandas can't do that.  It would be easier to just patch the string:   `newj = '{"alerts":' + oldjson + '}'`.

Comment: @Tim Roberts wow it worked! I didn't think I could do it this easily.. thanks lots for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Pandas cannot do what you ask.  You'll have to have pandas produce the JSON and do:

```
newjson = '{"alerts":' + oldjson + '}'
```